# Group together two columns with ID, do the cumulative for two columns

Tags: r, cumsum

Edit: I wrote the question way to unstructured, let me try again.

I want to create two new columns, `winner_total_points` and `loser_total_points` to the dataset below.

```
winner <- c(1,2,3,4,1,2)
loser <- c(2,3,1,3,3,1)
winner_points <- c(5,4,12,2,1,6)
loser_points <- c(5,2,2,6,6,2)
test_data <- data.frame(winner, loser, winner_points, loser_points)
```

What I want those two columns to do is that `winner_total_points` to sum all the points the winner has gotten (excluding this match) as both the winner and the loser.

The same function for `loser_total_points` but for the loser.

Note that the `winner` and `loser` columns contain the respective player ids.

Now, it's fairly easy using the `ave()` function but that only works for grouping only column and doing the cumulative sum for one column.

Desired output:

```
winner loser winner_points loser_points winner_total loser_total
1      2     5             5            5            5
2      3     4             2            9 (5+4)      2
3      1     12            2            14 (2+12)    7 (5+2)
4      3     2             6            2            20 (2+12+6)
1      3     1             6            8 (5+2+1)    26 (2+12+6+6)
2      1     6             2            15 (5+4+6)   10 (5+2+1+2)
```

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example

Comment: I can provide an example dataset you can load in.

Comment: I don't follow the logic.

Comment: @Sotos I've now rewritten the question. Hopefully it makes more sense now.

Comment: It would help if you gave the desired output for the sample input so that we can verify possible solutions

Comment: Still not clear to me.

Comment: @Sotos - I've posted a desired output.

Comment: I m sorry. I can't understand the logic. Maybe If you add the calculations for each value.

Comment: @Sotos - I just added the calculation that is done in the winner_total and loser_total column.

It's like, when 1 one is competing, what is his/her total score as both a loser and winner up to that point.

Comment: The question asks *to sum all the points the winner has gotten (**excluding** this match)* (emphasis mine) but the expected result has the cumulative sum *including* the actual match.

Answer (score 1):

I also am having trouble understanding but maybe this...?

```
library(dplyr)

as.winner <- test_data %>% group_by(winner) %>% summarise(winner_sum = sum(winner_points))
as.loser <- test_data %>% group_by(loser) %>% summarise(loser_sum = sum(loser_points))
names(as.winner)[1] <- 'player'
names(as.loser)[1] <- 'player'
totals <- merge(as.winner, as.loser, by = 'player', all.x = T, all.y = T)
totals[is.na(totals)] <- 0
totals <- transform(totals, total_points = winner_sum + loser_sum)
totals
```

Answer (score 0):

If I have correctly understood OP's requirements, he wants to compute a cumulative sum of the points by player id irrespective if winner_points or loser_points. The important point here is to note that the `winner` and `loser` columns contain the respective player ids.

The solution below reshapes the data from wide to long format whereby two value variables are reshaped simultaneously, computes the cumulative sums for each player id, and finally reshapes from long back to wide format, again.

```
library(data.table
cols <- c("winner", "loser")
setDT(test_data)[
  # append row id column required for subsequent reshaping
  , rn := .I][
    # reshape multiple value variables simultaneously from wide to long format
    , melt(.SD, id.vars = "rn", 
           measure.vars = list(cols, paste0(cols, "_points")), 
           value.name = c("id", "points"))][
             # rename variable column
             , variable := forcats::lvls_revalue(variable, cols)][
               # order by row id and compute cumulative points by id
               order(rn), total := cumsum(points), by = id][
                 # reshape multiple value variables simultaneously from long to wide format
                 , dcast(.SD, rn ~ variable, value.var = c("id", "points", "total"))]
```

> ```
>    rn id_winner id_loser points_winner points_loser total_winner total_loser
> 1:  1         1        2             5            5            5           5
> 2:  2         2        3             4            2            9           2
> 3:  3         3        1            12            2           14           7
> 4:  4         4        3             2            6            2          20
> 5:  5         1        3             1            6            8          26
> 6:  6         2        1             6            2           15          10
> ```

**Edit:** Above result is in line with the expected result posted by the OP.
 It includes the scored points *including* the actual match. Meanwhile, [the OP has posted a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47678197/3817004) where the expected result *excludes* the actual match.