# How can I create a column that cumulatively adds the sum of two previous rows based on conditions?

Tags: r, for-loop, cumulative-sum

I tried asking this question before but was it was poorly stated. This is a new attempt cause I haven't solved it yet.

I have a dataset with winners, losers, date, winner_points and loser_points.

For each row, I want two new columns, one for the winner and one for the loser that shows how many points they have scored so far (as both winners and losers).

Example data:

```
winner <- c(1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3)
loser <-  c(3,1,1,2,1,1,3,1,2)
date <- c("2017-10-01","2017-10-02","2017-10-03","2017-10-04","2017-10-05","2017-10-06","2017-10-07","2017-10-08","2017-10-09")
winner_points <- c(2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2)
loser_points <- c(1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1)
test_data <- data.frame(winner, loser, date = as.Date(date), winner_points, loser_points)
```

I want the output to be:

```
winner_points_sum <- c(0, 0, 1, 3, 1, 3, 5, 3, 5)
loser_points_sum <- c(0, 2, 2, 1, 4, 5, 4, 7, 4)
test_data <- data.frame(winner, loser, date = as.Date(date), winner_points, loser_points, winner_points_sum, loser_points_sum)
```

How I've solved it thus far is to do a for loop such as:

```
library(dplyr)
test_data$winner_points_sum_loop <- 0
test_data$loser_points_sum_loop <- 0

for(i in row.names(test_data)) {
  test_data[i,]$winner_points_sum_loop <-
    (
    test_data %>%
      dplyr::filter(winner == test_data[i,]$winner & date < test_data[i,]$date) %>%
      dplyr::summarise(points = sum(winner_points, na.rm = TRUE))
  +
    test_data %>%
      dplyr::filter(loser == test_data[i,]$winner & date < test_data[i,]$date) %>%
      dplyr::summarise(points = sum(loser_points, na.rm = TRUE))
    )
}

test_data$winner_points_sum_loop <- unlist(test_data$winner_points_sum_loop)
```

Any suggestions how to tackle this problem? The queries take quite some time when the row numbers add up. I've tried elaborating with the AVE function, I can do it for one column to sum a players point as winner but can't figure out how to add their points as loser.

[image: This is the end result (except last column)]

Comment: I don't understand what `winner_points_sum` should be. Is it the sum from all `winner_points` from the rows above it? Can you clarify that?

Comment: I'm utterly confused. What do the `winner` and `loser` points mean? Why is winner 1 and loser 3? How did you get to `winner_points` and `loser_points`. And what does the loop do? Please clarify some of this?

Comment: winner_points_sum is supposed to be the sum of that winners points on their all previous matches, both when they were the winner and the loser.

The winner and loser are IDs, just examples, same with the points.

@MattW @D Pinto

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
winner <- c(1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3)
loser <-  c(3,1,1,2,1,1,3,1,2)
date <- c("2017-10-01","2017-10-02","2017-10-03","2017-10-04","2017-10-05","2017-10-06","2017-10-07","2017-10-08","2017-10-09")
winner_points <- c(2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2)
loser_points <- c(1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1)
test_data <- data.frame(winner, loser, date = as.Date(date), winner_points, loser_points)


library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

test_data %>%
  unite(winner, winner, winner_points) %>%                    # unite winner columns
  unite(loser, loser, loser_points) %>%                       # unite loser columns
  gather(type, pl_pts, winner, loser, -date) %>%              # reshape
  separate(pl_pts, c("player","points"), convert = T) %>%     # separate columns
  arrange(date) %>%                                           # order dates (in case it's not)
  group_by(player) %>%                                        # for each player
  mutate(sum_points = cumsum(points) - points) %>%            # get points up to that date
  ungroup() %>%                                               # forget the grouping
  unite(pl_pts_sumpts, player, points, sum_points) %>%        # unite columns
  spread(type, pl_pts_sumpts) %>%                             # reshape
  separate(loser, c("loser", "loser_points", "loser_points_sum"), convert = T) %>%                # separate columns and give appropriate names
  separate(winner, c("winner", "winner_points", "winner_points_sum"), convert = T) %>%
  select(winner, loser, date, winner_points, loser_points, winner_points_sum, loser_points_sum)   # select the order you prefer


# # A tibble: 9 x 7
#   winner loser       date winner_points loser_points winner_points_sum loser_points_sum
# *  <int> <int>     <date>         <int>        <int>             <int>            <int>
# 1      1     3 2017-10-01             2            1                 0                0
# 2      2     1 2017-10-02             1            0                 0                2
# 3      3     1 2017-10-03             2            1                 1                2
# 4      1     2 2017-10-04             1            0                 3                1
# 5      2     1 2017-10-05             2            1                 1                4
# 6      3     1 2017-10-06             1            0                 3                5
# 7      1     3 2017-10-07             2            1                 5                4
# 8      2     1 2017-10-08             1            0                 3                7
# 9      3     2 2017-10-09             2            1                 5                4
```

Comment: Yeah, this is a way to solve it I never thought about. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I finally understood what you want. And I took an approach of getting cumulative points of each player at each point in time and then joining it to the original `test_data` data frame.

```
winner <- c(1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3)
loser <-  c(3,1,1,2,1,1,3,1,2)
date <- c("2017-10-01","2017-10-02","2017-10-03","2017-10-04","2017-10-05","2017-10-06","2017-10-07","2017-10-08","2017-10-09")
winner_points <- c(2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2)
loser_points <- c(1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1)
test_data <- data.frame(winner, loser, date = as.Date(date), winner_points, loser_points)

library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

cum_points <- test_data %>% 
  gather(end_game_status, player_id, winner, loser) %>% 
  gather(which_point, how_many_points, winner_points, loser_points) %>% 
  filter(
    (end_game_status == "winner" & which_point == "winner_points") | 
      (end_game_status == "loser" & which_point == "loser_points")) %>% 
  arrange(date = as.Date(date)) %>% 
  group_by(player_id) %>% 
  mutate(cumulative_points = cumsum(how_many_points)) %>% 
  mutate(cumulative_points_sofar = lag(cumulative_points, default = 0))
  select(player_id, date, cumulative_points)

output <- test_data %>% 
  left_join(cum_points, by = c('date', 'winner' = 'player_id')) %>% 
  rename(winner_points_sum = cumulative_points_sofar) %>% 
  left_join(cum_points, by = c('date', 'loser' = 'player_id')) %>% 
  rename(loser_points_sum = cumulative_points_sofar)
output
```

Answer (score 0):

The difference to the [previous question of the OP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44591583/3817004) is that the OP is now asking for the cumulative sum of points each player has scored *so far*, i.e., before the actual date. Furthermore, the sample data set now contains a `date` column which uniquely identifies each row.

So, [my previous approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47705647/3817004) can be used here as well, with some modifications. The solution below reshapes the data from wide to long format whereby two value variables are reshaped simultaneously, computes the cumulative sums for each player id , and finally reshapes from long back to wide format, again. In order to sum only points scored *before* the actual date, the rows are lagged by one.

It is important to note that the `winner` and `loser` columns contain the respective player ids.

```
library(data.table)
cols <- c("winner", "loser")
setDT(test_data)[
  # reshape multiple value variables simultaneously from wide to long format
  , melt(.SD, id.vars = "date", 
         measure.vars = list(cols, paste0(cols, "_points")), 
         value.name = c("id", "points"))][
           # rename variable column
           , variable := forcats::lvls_revalue(variable, cols)][
             # order by date and cumulate the lagged points by id
             order(date), points_sum := cumsum(shift(points, fill = 0)), by = id][
               # reshape multiple value variables simultaneously from long to wide format
               , dcast(.SD, date ~ variable, value.var = c("id", "points", "points_sum"))]
```

> ```
>          date id_winner id_loser points_winner points_loser points_sum_winner points_sum_loser
> 1: 2017-10-01         1        3             2            1                 0                0
> 2: 2017-10-02         2        1             1            0                 0                2
> 3: 2017-10-03         3        1             2            1                 1                2
> 4: 2017-10-04         1        2             1            0                 3                1
> 5: 2017-10-05         2        1             2            1                 1                4
> 6: 2017-10-06         3        1             1            0                 3                5
> 7: 2017-10-07         1        3             2            1                 5                4
> 8: 2017-10-08         2        1             1            0                 3                7
> 9: 2017-10-09         3        2             2            1                 5                4
> ```